# Running sDist to build a package and install creates empty Build Directory

Tags: python, distutils, sdist

created a setup file. with the following code where setup.py is

```
import sys
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='SomePackage',
    author='dave',
    version='0.1.0',
    author_email='dave',
    packages=['apples',],
    license='LICENSE.txt',
    url="None",
    include_package_data=True,
    description='i love apples',
    long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
    install_requires=[
        "matplotlib >= 2.0.0",
        "numpy >= 1.11.3",
        "openpyxl >= 2.4.1",
        "openturns >= 1.9",
        "pandas >= 0.19.2",
        "pip >= 9.0.1",
        "pyodbc >= 4.0.17",
        "pyqt >= 5.6.0",
        "pywin32 >= 220.0.0",
        "pywinauto >= 0.6.3",
        "qt >= 5.6.2",
        "scipy >= 0.18.1",
        "statistics >= 1.0.3.5",
        "tqdm >= 4.15.0",
        "xlwings >= 0.10.2",
    ], )
```

when running python setup.py sdist, the result creates a dist folder with a zip file (I am on windows). when opening this file the apples package and all the sub folders are within it. the directory tree for apples is as follows

**note** in the screenshot, the Files indicates they are in the Apples folder.

[image]

however when I deploy to another machine by

1. unzipping zip file
2. cd to dir
3. python setup.py install
4. a build folder is created in site-packages/apples
5. within the build folder which gets copied to the site-packages folder is just two files (**init**.py and version.py), leaving out the sub dirs of core and slice

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to list all packages and subpackges:

```
packages=['apples', 'apples.core', 'apples.slice',],
```

or

```
from setuptools import find_packages
…
packages = find_packages(),
```

Comment: thank you! i just added the sub-packages as you mentioned. however setuptools is quite nice, and in some cases I think its the best way to go.